# Applying formula to variable time series in R

Tags: r, date, time-series, analytics, subset

I have a Data frame in R for which I have to run a retention report. I need to run the retention formula for a sequence/subsets of the df's sale month-year.

```
Sale_date,  Cancel_date,  days_to_cancel, sale_month;

2015-01-01, 2015-04-06,  95,              2015-01;  
2015-04-01,           , NA,              2015-04;  
2015-10-31, 2015-11-02, 3,               2015-10;  
2013-05-20, 2014-05-20, 365,             2013-05;
```

I have formatted the columns of the membership sale date and cancellation date as.Date. I also created a new column df$days_to_cancellation as.numeric, to give me the number of days It took for the membership to cancel (cancellation date-sale date, na.strings=NA), and the sale_month column to make it easier to sequence. I calculate the retention % with the formula: 
(1-(x_days_Cancel_rate))  where x could be either 15,30,60,90,120 etc...days

For example, to calculate the 60-day retention of memberships sold in October I would use:

```
October_Retention<-1-(sum(df$sale_date>="2015-10-01"&df$sale_date<"2015-11-01"&df$days_to_cancel<=60,na.rm=T)/sum(df$sale_date>="2015-10-01"&df$sale_date<"2015-11-01")
```

which correctly provides the 60 day retention of memberships sold in October.

My questions is, besides manually creating a Month*_Retention object for each month and for each X day variable, is there another way of telling R to run the formula for the months of January-December for 30- 60- 90 -120 day retention for example? I need a way to tell R to run the formula per sales month and per variable x-days.

I have been running this particular report for years in excel, and I might just be approaching the issue the wrong way. attached is an image for what I am trying to accomplish in R.

Any and all input would be appreciated

[retention graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpB9D.jpg)

Comment: Please use the proper formatting layout options for readability.

Comment: Rather than do that painful double logical test, wouldn't it be easier to make a variable with `cut.Date` using by="1 month"? Then you would have a classification variable to pass to aggregate-type functions. You can also then use `cut` on days to cancel and then work with `interaction` of the two. Please don't go down the SAS/SPSS/BASIC rabbit hole of constructing umpteeen copies of named objects.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems like the cut.Date did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr, you can obtain monthly rates as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
report <- df %>%
  group_by(sale_month) %>%
  summarise(retention30 = round(sum(is.na(days_to_cancel) | days_to_cancel > 30) / n() * 100, 1),
            rentention60 = round(sum(is.na(days_to_cancel) | days_to_cancel > 60) / n() * 100, 1))
```

In this case, I am treating no cancellation in every retention period. You can modify the criteria to satisfy what you want in this regard.